# Why do scroll bars appear on my image element?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have [the following simple code](http://jsfiddle.net/jfzbV/):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src='http://i51.tinypic.com/4kz4g5.jpg' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 260px;
    height: 195px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #333;
}
```

The dimensions of the image are `width=260px, height=195px`, which is exactly like the dimensions of the `div`.

My question is why the scroll bars appears in this situation ? (I expect them to appear only if image dimensions are greater of `div`'s dimensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the fact that img is an inline tag, so it leaves space for text ascenders and descenders. Set the img to `display: block` and it'll work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's because an empty text node is being inserted in your `<div>` and adding just enough space to require scrollbars.  You can fix it with the following CSS:

```
div {
    width: 260px;
    height: 195px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #333;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

[In action here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfzbV/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to the `img`.

[See it](http://jsfiddle.net/jfzbV/3/).

Answer (score -1):

Divs by default have padding values, you should set them to 0.

```
padding: 0px;
```